# HTML5 closing tag /> for meta or stylesheets

Tags: html, tags

There are certain doctypes that need the closing tag `/>` and there are others that need just a `>`.

For example, `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />` 
or `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" >`

How is this with HTML5? Is it anything I need to consider?

Comment: Here's [the relevant section of the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#elements-0). In HTML5, as stated in other comments, it is allowable but not necessary for void elements (such as `link`, `meta`, `br`); for foreign elements (see the link for what those are) it marks the tag as self-closing. For all others, it is not valid as those elements all require a closing tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tags that have an opening and closing tag (anchors, span, divs, etc) don't need a /> because the / is in the closing tag.

Tags that stand alone (br, hr, img, etc.) are supposed to have a /> now.

As far as I understand, it's not necessary, but was put in play for HTML5 for the sake of consistency with XML and XHTML.

I have read that you should put a space before the /> as to not confuse older browsers.

Comment: For HTML documents under HTML5, there's no need for `/>`. You can use them, but there's no real benefit.